# How to display extra attributes for a collection check box

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

How can i display more details for items in a collection check box. the only details i can provide in my form is the checkbox and the text due to the Tag helper, i also want to display details like picture of the item or description of the item.

Currently this is what i am doing

```
      <%= f.collection_check_boxes(
                  :logo_type_ids, LogoType.all, :id, :name, allow_destroy: true
          ) do |b, c| %>
          <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            <% logo_type = LogoType.where(id: b.value).first %>
            <div class="thumbnail">
              <%= image_tag(logo_type.example(:original)) %>
              <div class="caption">
                <h3><%= b.label { b.check_box + b.text } %></h3>
                <p><%= logo_type.description %></p>
               </div>
            </div>
          </div>
      <% end %>
```

The code above works but i dont think its the right approach. Any ideas how this can be handled. Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two suggestions.  First, I'd make sure that the controller is loading all the LogoType objects for you.  That's its job (SRP).  By doing this you'll save a lot of unnecessary trips to the DB.  Specifically, in the code below, the second line pulls the LogoType out of the collection rather than hitting the DB each time.

```
<%= f.collection_check_boxes(:logo_type_ids, @logo_types, :id, :name, allow_destroy: true) do |b, c| %>
  <% logo_type = @logo_types.detect{|logo| logo.id == b.value } %>
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <%= image_tag(logo_type.example %>
      <div class="caption">
        <h3><%= b.label { b.check_box + b.text } %></h3>
        <p><%= logo_type.description %></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Second, I'd strongly consider wrapping *everything* in the outermost div into a helper method.    The helper could accept the logo_type and 'b' and either build the markup using content_tag or  render a partial and pass the logo_type and b to the partial as locals.  This option would make your markup much more expressive.

```
<%= f.collection_check_boxes(:logo_type_ids, @logo_types, :id, :name, allow_destroy: true) do |b, c| %>
  <% logo_type = @logo_types.detect{|logo| logo.id == b.value } %>
  <%= logo_type_collection_checkbox logo_type, b %>
<% end %>
```